# How can I optimize this Lua function?

Tags: string, lua

Currently just looking for a way to make this code faster.

This function currently takes in a string, `s`, and an int, `k`, and returns the substring of `s` length `k` with the most vowels.

Example:

```
s = caberqiitefg
k = 5
```

Output:

```
erqii
```

erqii is a substring of length 5 with the most vowels in `s`.

Returns “Not found!” if there are no vowels in the string.

```
function findSubstring(s, k)
    local sub = string.sub
    local gsub = string.gsub
    local vowels = "[aeiou]"
    local empty = ""
    local _, numberOfVowels = gsub(s, vowels, empty)
    if numberOfVowels == 0 then
        return "Not found!"
    end
    local mostVowels = nil
    local vowelnum = 0
    for i = 1, #s - k + 1 do
        local curr = sub(s, i, k + i - 1)
        local _, nvow = gsub(curr, vowels, empty)
        if mostVowels == nil or (nvow > vowelnum) then
            mostVowels = curr
            vowelnum = nvow
        end
    end
    return mostVowels
end
```

Comment: Write benchmarks and try things.

Comment: Is re-implementing it in C not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but I found that this modified version runs better in some cases

```lua
function findSubstring2(s, k)
    local sub = string.sub
    local gsub = string.gsub
    local vowels = "[aeiou]"
    local empty = ""
    local _, numberOfVowels = gsub(s, vowels, empty)
    if numberOfVowels == 0 then
        return "Not found!"
    end

    local candidate = nil
    local vowelnum = 0
    local i=1
    while i <= #s-k+1 do
        local curr = sub(s, i, k + i - 1)
        local _, nvow = gsub(curr, vowels, empty)
        if nvow > vowelnum then
            candidate = curr
            vowelnum = nvow
        end
        i=i+(curr:find(vowels) or #curr)
    end
    return candidate
end
```

As you can see, it always skips to the next vowel, which 1. makes it faster for high `k` in a long `s` with long chains of consonants before the target string and 2. means it might skip a valid sequence has its first vowel after `#s-k` (the last position where the substring could start), which you'd have to mitigate with some special case.

Whether this speedup is worth it depends on what your average input string looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = 'caberqiitefg'
k = 5
j = k
max = 0
max_sub = ""
arr = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
for i in range(len(str1)):
    sub = str1[i:j]
    p= 0
    for m in arr:
        p += sub.count(m)
    if p!= 0 and p>max:
        max = p
        max_sub = sub
    j+=1
print(max_sub)
```

I used few variables and a list to decrease the space complexity.